# ReactJs & Flux: Fetching data when routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, url-routing, flux

Tools: Reactjs 0.14.0,Vanilla Flux, React-Router

My question are all in bold.

Generally, **should it only be the top-level component(controller-view) where all data is loaded into the store?**(in the componentDidMount method)

I ask because I've been confused because of the following:

When dealing with routing(different sub-trees of child components) the data needed to render will change depending on what child sub-tree is displayed.

**I'm guessing we would just grab all the data for all the components(included the ones not yet rendered) and put it into the store. Is that about right for most cases?**

But when I consider making things fast and smooth -I'm assuming,depending on the routing, you might want to make special web api calls for data-heavy components that are initially needed or to refresh
some of the data for that particular component.

**Is it okay to delegate some loading to child components or is that going to get me into trouble?**

Comment: It's ok, unless you want to make the app isomorphic, in that case Node would need to ask a route "give me all the data I need to render the content". In that case you can put it all at the top route, or do something clever which traverses and collects all necessary data.

Comment: Another issue with fetching data from child components is if a child component is only rendered once a request higher up in the component tree resolves, then you will end up requesting data sequentially rather than in parallel.